# AWS Amplify Custom Resolver - Unsupported operation 'BatchPutItem'

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, vtl

I'm following some guides to implement a custom resolver with `BatchPutItem` operation.  Currently I'm facing some issues which I can't get right.

- **The error output**

```json
{
  "data": {
    "batchAddBusiness": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "batchAddBusiness"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Unsupported operation 'BatchPutItem'."
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the necessary data:

- **Schema**

```graphql
type Business 
  @model (subscriptions: { level: off })
  @auth (rules: [
    {allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"]},
    {allow: groups, groups: ["BusinessOwner"]}
  ])
  @key(fields: ["id", "createdAt"])
{
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  phone: String!
  email: String!
  createdAt: String!
  hours: [OpenHours]
  specialHours: [SpecialHours]
  category: [BusinessCategory] @connection(keyName: "byBusiness", fields: ["id"])
  lists: [BusinessList] @connection(keyName: "byBusiness", fields: ["id"])
  tags: [BusinessTags] @connection(keyName: "byBusiness", fields: ["id"])
  users: [BusinessUsers] @connection(keyName: "byBusiness", fields: ["id"])
}

type Mutation {
  batchAddBusiness(business: [CreateBusinessInput]): [Business]
}
```

- **Mutation**

```grapqhl
mutation batchAdd {
  batchAddBusiness(business: [
  {
    id: "6726da58-a8af-4656-9a8a-9c7453455e28",
    name: "Company A",
    phone: "+12341235",
    email: "office@notexists2.com",
    createdAt: "2020-03-01"
  },
  {
    id: "6726da58-a8af-4656-9a8a-9c7453455e23",
    name: "Asdf",
    phone: "+12341235",
    email: "office@notexists.com",
    createdAt: "2020-03-02"
  }
  ]) {
    id name phone email createdAt
  }
}
```

- **Mutation.batchAddBusiness.req.vtl**

```
## [Start] Determine request authentication mode **
#if( $util.isNullOrEmpty($authMode) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.sub) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.issuer) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.username) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.claims) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.sourceIp) && !$util.isNull($ctx.identity.defaultAuthStrategy) )
#set( $authMode = "userPools" )
#end
## [End] Determine request authentication mode **
## [Start] Check authMode and execute owner/group checks **
#if( $authMode == "userPools" )
    ## [Start] Static Group Authorization Checks **
    #set($isStaticGroupAuthorized = $util.defaultIfNull(
                $isStaticGroupAuthorized, false))
    ## Authorization rule: { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"], groupClaim: "cognito:groups" } **
    #set( $userGroups = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("cognito:groups"), []) )
    #set( $allowedGroups = ["Admin"] )
    #foreach( $userGroup in $userGroups )
        #if( $allowedGroups.contains($userGroup) )
        #set( $isStaticGroupAuthorized = true )
        #break
        #end
    #end
    ## Authorization rule: { allow: groups, groups: ["BusinessOwner"], groupClaim: "cognito:groups" } **
    #set( $userGroups = $util.defaultIfNull($ctx.identity.claims.get("cognito:groups"), []) )
    #set( $allowedGroups = ["BusinessOwner"] )
    #foreach( $userGroup in $userGroups )
        #if( $allowedGroups.contains($userGroup) )
        #set( $isStaticGroupAuthorized = true )
        #break
        #end
    #end
    ## [End] Static Group Authorization Checks **

    ## No Dynamic Group Authorization Rules **
    ## No Owner Authorization Rules **

    ## [Start] Throw if unauthorized **
    #if( !($isStaticGroupAuthorized == true || $isDynamicGroupAuthorized == true || $isOwnerAuthorized == true) )
        $util.unauthorized()
    #end
    ## [End] Throw if unauthorized **
#end
## [End] Check authMode and execute owner/group checks **

#set($businessdata = [])
#foreach($item in ${ctx.args.business})
    $util.qr($item.put("createdAt", $util.time.nowISO8601()))
    $util.qr($item.put("updatedAt", $util.time.nowISO8601()))
    $util.qr($item.put("__typename", "Business"))
    $util.qr($item.put("id", $util.defaultIfNullOrBlank($item.id, $util.autoId())))
    $util.qr($businessdata.add($util.dynamodb.toMapValues($item)))
    ## $util.qr($ctx.stash.put("debugthis", $businessdata))
#end
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "operation": "BatchPutItem",
  "tables": {
      "Business-asdf1234-dev": $utils.toJson($businessdata)
  }
}
```

- **Mutation.batchAddBusiness.res.vtl**

```
#if ($ctx.error)
    $util.appendError($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type, null, $ctx.result.data.unprocessedKeys)
#end
$util.toJson($ctx.result.data["Business-asdf1234-dev"])
```

- **Cloudwatch RequestMapping**

```json
{
    "logType": "RequestMapping",
    "path": [
        "batchAddBusiness"
    ],
    "fieldName": "batchAddBusiness",
    "resolverArn": "arn:aws:appsync:eu-west-1:12312312123:apis/asdf1234/types/Mutation/fields/batchAddBusiness",
    "requestId": "7ba690f3-74eb-400c-bbe9-49325241bc45",
    "context": {
        "arguments": {
            "business": [
                {
                    "id": "6726da58-a8af-4656-9a8a-9c7453455e28",
                    "name": "Company A",
                    "phone": "+12341235",
                    "email": "office@notexists2.com",
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-05T15:37:43.614Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-05T15:37:43.614Z",
                    "__typename": "Business"
                },
                {
                    "id": "6726da58-a8af-4656-9a8a-9c7453455e23",
                    "name": "Asdf",
                    "phone": "+12341235",
                    "email": "office@notexists.com",
                    "createdAt": "2020-04-05T15:37:43.614Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-04-05T15:37:43.614Z",
                    "__typename": "Business"
                }
            ]
        },
        "stash": {},
        "outErrors": []
    },
    "fieldInError": true,
    "errors": [
        "Unable to transform Response Template"
    ],
    "parentType": "Mutation",
    "graphQLAPIId": "alsdkasldksaasdlkasdkl",
    "transformedTemplate": "                                                    \n\n    \n\n    \n\n            \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    \n        \n    \n    \n    \n    \n    {\n  \"version\": \"2018-05-29\",\n  \"operation\": \"BatchPutItem\",\n  \"tables\": {\n      \"Business-asdf1234-dev\": [{\"createdAt\":{\"S\":\"2020-04-05T15:37:43.614Z\"},\"phone\":{\"S\":\"+12341235\"},\"__typename\":{\"S\":\"Business\"},\"name\":{\"S\":\"Company A\"},\"id\":{\"S\":\"6726da58-a8af-4656-9a8a-9c7453455e28\"},\"email\":{\"S\":\"office@notexists2.com\"},\"updatedAt\":{\"S\":\"2020-04-05T15:37:43.614Z\"}},{\"createdAt\":{\"S\":\"2020-04-05T15:37:43.614Z\"},\"phone\":{\"S\":\"+12341235\"},\"__typename\":{\"S\":\"Business\"},\"name\":{\"S\":\"Stiegenwirt\"},\"id\":{\"S\":\"6726da58-a8af-4656-9a8a-9c7453455e23\"},\"email\":{\"S\":\"office@notexists.com\"},\"updatedAt\":{\"S\":\"2020-04-05T15:37:43.614Z\"}}]\n  }\n}"
}
```

Comment: did you enable Data Source Versioning on you DDB datasource tied to the `Mutation.batchAddBusiness `? If yes, then you can't use `BatchPutItem`.

Comment: Hi yes Data Source Versioning prevents Batch Operations like here discussed: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3889 But you can write an answer since you we're on the right track! Thanks!

Comment: @KevinRegenrek are you able to solve this issue? if yes, then can you please post the solution here? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: ```"Unsupported operation 'BatchPutItem'. Datasource Versioning only supports the following operations (TransactGetItems,PutItem,BatchGetItem,Scan,Query,GetItem,DeleteItem,UpdateItem,Sync)"
``` I am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by disabling datastore for the entire api.
Here is how, you can also do this:

```
$ amplify update api
$ Graphql
$ remove datastore for entire API
```

Then `amplify push`, now it will remove the `_version` field from each you the dataType (`build/schema.graphql`). And, everything will work fine, you no longer need to pass  `_version`. Now BatchPutItem is working fine for me.

Comment: Performing those command line operations doesn't give an option to remove DataStore for me. Suggest trying https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/4082#issuecomment-622508016